# Can't get the right selector for .replaceWith method

Tags: jquery, radio-button, replacewith

Having some problems with this piece of code, i want to replace the piece of html code that defines what the background is upon selecting a choice from the radio button options. I can't seem to get the selector right.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#getValue').click(function(){
                var input = $('input[name=choice]:checked').val();
                });
            if(input = 1)
            {
                $('#background').replaceWith('<img src="image source 1" alt="Background should be displayed here">');
            }
            if(input = 2)
            {
                $('#background').replaceWith('<img src="image source 2" alt="Background should be displayed here">');
            }
            if(input = 3)
            {
                $('#background').replaceWith('<img src="image source 3" alt="Background should be displayed here">');
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body id="body">

<div id="background">
        <img src="image source 1" alt="Background should be displayed here">
</div>

<div id="footer">
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" />Scheme A
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="2" />Scheme B
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="3" />Scheme C
        <input type="button" id="getValue" value="SELECT SCHEME"/>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Select the image:

```
$('#background img').replaceWith(' ... ');
```

Instead of replacing the element, just update its attributes:

```
$('#background img').attr({
    'src': 'image source X',
    'alt': 'Background should be displayed here'
});
```

Comment: Yet another option is to use [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `replaceInner`: `$('#background').html(' ... ');`